# How to make regex that validate country code in phone number

Tags: javascript, asp.net, regex, validation

I am creating `asp.net regex validator` that should validate mobile number with country code.
Number can be like: **+41 44 221 21 20 or 0041 44 221 21 20 or same without spaces**.
I have tried something but it doesn't work:

```
\+(9[976]\d|8[987530]\d|6[987]\d|5[90]\d|42\d|3[875]\d|
2[98654321]\d|9[8543210]|8[6421]|6[6543210]|5[87654321]|
4[987654310]|3[9643210]|2[70]|7|1)
\W*\d\W*\d\W*\d\W*\d\W*\d\W*\d\W*\d\W*\d\W*(\d{1,2})$
```

How to make regex for this validation?

Comment: I would not use a (single) regular expression for this. The amount of different valid phone numbers is quite .. ridiculous. Anyway, if I wanted to verify that a country code was possibly valid, I would extract the first numbers (e.g. as a simple \d) and then compare it against [a list of valid codes](http://www.howtocallabroad.com/codes.html). And then, *after* that, possibly apply one of the many heuristics to determine if the remainder of the number "might be valid" .. or just say, "all numbers, dashes, or spaces = Ok".

Comment: @user2864740 Should be posted as an answer, I beleive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that your list of country codes is correct, the following should work:

```
^(\+|00)(9[976]\d|8[987530]\d|6[987]\d|5[90]\d|42\d|3[875]\d|2[98654321]\d|9[8543210]|8[6421]|6[6543210]|5[87654321]|4[987654310]|3[9643210]|2[70]|7|1)(\s?\d){9}$
```

Matches can start with `+` or `00`, followed by a country code, followed by a sequence of 9 numbers which can be divided by spaces.

Note: If you are trying to match these numbers inside a longer string, remove the `^` and `$` from the ends of the regex.

[Working on RegexPal](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%28%5C%2B%7C00%29%289%5B976%5D%7C8%5B987530%5D%7C6%5B987%5D%7C5%5B90%5D%7C42%7C3%5B875%5D%7C2%5B98654321%5D%7C9%5B8543210%5D%7C8%5B6421%5D%7C6%5B6543210%5D%7C5%5B87654321%5D%7C4%5B987654310%5D%7C3%5B9643210%5D%7C2%5B70%5D%7C7%7C1%29%28%5Cs%3F%5Cd%29%7B9%7D&input=%2B41%2044%20221%2021%2020%0A0041%2044%20221%2021%2020%0A%2B41442212120%0A0041442212120)